# Linux clean install on an HP ThinClient

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

I'm having some issues with installing and removing stuff in Linux. I have a HP ThinClient (T5325) and was following these instructions to remove the HP OS and set up a Debian OS:
http://41j.com/blog/2011/10/hp-t5325-thin-client-hacked-to-full-debian-system/

At one point I had to go someplace and when I came back the ThinClient was frozen so I rebooted it. After that nothing really works for me. I can't remove programs or add any (if I try it always says that some dpkg list files are missing and it also always tries to remove hptc-control-center but fails).

I also noticed that there is little space left of the built in 512mb flash drive. So I was wondering if there was a way from bash to just remove everything non essential to bash and networking?

I have tried to plug in an USB stick and boot either Ubuntu or the HP ThinState to restore the ThinClient (I took a backup) but I can't boot to USB. The HP site and other sites say just plug in the USB and press the power button 2 or 3 times. But on my device the power button does nothing. The moment I plug in power the device turns on and the led on ther power button turns on.

Answer (score 2):

You propably currupted the filesystem from the flash-drive. I had recently a similar effect with a USB-stick - after canceling an ongoing copy-operation it marked the usb-stick as full - although nothing was written.

So propably a full file-system-check should give you space again.